# User Location Prediction

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to predict the user location for a mobile app for a certain timestamp. So far I've gathered training data throughout different days. The data contains the latitude, longitude and the timestamp.

What would be the best algorithm/best way in order to train a model that takes a timestamp as an input and gives as output a latitude and longitude pair?

Comment: So you have lat/ long/ date/ time. What else? Perhaps you can add some more features - day of week (imp), weather (not sure whether Accuweather will give you past data too). Think through, and you may be able to put in a few more relevant features. Once you have rich data, you can go ahead to slice-and-dice it to discover patterns - that'll be the foundation of your prediction model.

Comment: Latitude, longitude, and timestamp are the only features for now. I could easily add the day of the week, but I don't want to take into the account the weather or any other stuff. I only want to predict the location (latitude-longitude pair) given the timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KNN:**

The prediction of Lat/Lng from a given timestep could be performed by analysing the previous data of the user. This is a totally naive approach but could be tried,

- Take an input timestamp from the user. Let's call it $x$.
- From the previous data of the user, search for the timestamp which is the closest to $x$.
- Once you find the closest timestamp, output the Lat/Lng associated with that timestamp.

> This approach is called **K-NN ( K Nearest Neighbours )** classification.
>   It will work well if the user is mostly at a common place at a given
>   time ( timestamp ).

**Clustering method:**

This method will work on making clusters of Lat/Lng. For some a given **time-interval**, suppose, you will get a common timestep ( which will be the centre of the cluster ).

- Once you have a cluster of timesteps, find the timestep ( centre of the cluster ) which is the closest to the input $x$.
- For this timestep, you will get Lat/Lng which close to one another.
- For predicting the Lat/Lng, use the centre of the cluster and output the associated Lat/Lng values.

> Basically, you are **clustering** similar data points which help in prediction. You can find where a user's location is clustered at given time intervals.

Comment: Also, try including more features as they would make predictions more user-centred.